# How to validate ROC and UENO Company Type with Input? (Singapore)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

I am supposed to select the Company Type, let's say UENO then the input will be validated. Company ROC or UENO  can be differentiate as follows:

**UENO**: it must start with alphabet “R” or “S” or “T” followed by 2 numeric, followed by 2 alphabets and 4 numeric and end with 1 alphabet.

**ROC** : - it must start with 9 numeric and end with 1 alphabet; OR
- start with “F” followed by 8 numeric and end with 1 alphabet.

Currently, this is what I have.

```
    public static bool IsValidUeno(string ueno)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ueno))
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Check length

        if (ueno.Length != 10)
        {
            return false;
        }

        char first = ueno.First();

        if (first != 'R' || first != 'S' || first != 'T')
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: This sounds like a perfect regex candidate

Answer (score 0):

You'll need regex to do this. For UENO it will be

(^R{1}|^S{1}|^T{1})(\d{2})([a-zA-Z]{2})(\d{4})([a-zA-Z]{1}$)

For ROC it will be

(^\d{9})([a-zA-Z]$)|(^F{1})(\d{8})([a-zA-Z]$)